# Get number string as output from a paragraph string

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, sed, grep

I have a output stored in a variable that comes from a `.jar` script

```
Token is: XYZ123
Not found in page: 0
Not found in page: 1
Not found in page: 2
Found with ID : #14214733
```

Now I want to extract the ID after `#` i.e `14214733` and want to store it in another variable, how do I do that in bash?

EDIT: Solved using `echo ${var##*#}`

Comment: Could you `echo` your variable here? Wouldn't `echo ${variable##*#}` work ?

Comment: The `echo $var` produces the above output as a whole, now I want to get the last ID

Comment: I just tried the above code, and it worked like a charm.
Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 2):

With bash, capture it with a regular expression

```bsh
output='Token is: XYZ123
Not found in page: 0
Not found in page: 1
Not found in page: 2
Found with ID : #14214733'

[[ $output =~ "Found with ID : #"([0-9]+) ]] && id=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}

echo $id    # => 14214733
```

In bash regular expressions, the literal text parts are quoted, and the regex-special stuff is not. Captured parts go into the BASH_REMATCH array.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be:

```
sec_var=`cat ts.txt | grep -oE 'ID : #([0-9]+)' | cut -f2 -d '#'`
sec_var=`echo $first_var | grep -oE 'ID : #([0-9]+)' | cut -f2 -d '#'`
```

Also you can use grep "-z" option:

> -z suppress newline at the end of line, substituting it for null character. That is, grep knows where end of line is, but sees the
> input as one big line.